# Log in to ASP website using Python's Requests module

Tags: python, asp.net, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

Im trying to webscrape some information from my school page, but im having hard time to get past login. I know there are similar threeds, i have spend whole day reading, but cannot make it work.

This is program im using (User name and password were changed):

```
import requests

payload = {'ctl00$cphmain$Loginname': 'name', 'ctl00$cphmain$TextBoxHeslo': 'password'}

page = requests.post('http://gymnaziumbma.no-ip.org:81/login.aspx', payload)
open_page = requests.get("http://gymnaziumbma.no-ip.org:81/prehled.aspx?s=44&c=prub")

#Check content
if page.text == open_page.text:
    print("Same page")
else:
    print(open_page.text)
    print("Different page!")
```

Can you tell me, what im doing wrong? Am i missing some parameter? Is requests good metod for this? I was trying robobrowser and BeautifulSoup, but doesnt work either. I bet im missing something really trivial.

Im using Python 3.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off,  you are not using a [Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) so even if your first post successfully logs you on the second knows nothing about it. Second, you are missing data that needs to be posted, *__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR* and *__VIEWSTATE* which you can parse from the source using *BeautifulSoup*:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {'ctl00$cphmain$Loginname': 'name', 'ctl00$cphmain$TextBoxHeslo': 'password'}
# A Session object will persist the login cookies.
with requests.Session() as s:
    page = s.get('http://gymnaziumbma.no-ip.org:81/login.aspx')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
    data["___VIEWSTATE"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")["value"]
    data["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"]
    s.post('http://gymnaziumbma.no-ip.org:81/login.aspx', data=data)
    open_page = s.get("http://gymnaziumbma.no-ip.org:81/prehled.aspx?s=44&c=prub")

    #Check content
    if page.text == open_page.text:
        print("Same page")
    else:
        print(open_page.text)
        print("Different page!")
```

You can see all the form data that gets posted in Chrome dev tools.

[image]

What is posted above should be enough to get logged in, if not any value you need can be parsed from the login table using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I did not know about the session. When i try to use your solution, i get the same error i had when i was trying to use RoboBrowser: `code: data["__viewstate"] = soup.select_one("#__viewstate")["value"] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` . Do you have any idea why it can happen?

Comment: Yep, I should have used all capitals for   `__VIEWSTATE`, it should work fine now.

Comment: Thank you a lot. After adding three another parameters to data it works fine :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Hi, I tried this code but got this error `if page.text == open_page.text:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
`
So I commented those lines and tried `print open_page.content` which printed the content of the **login page** instead of the intended page to open after login, any suggestion please? Edit: printing `open_page` alone gives **Response 200**.

Comment: @KiDo, what site are you trying to login to?