# Login to aspx website using python requests

Tags: python, asp.net, authentication, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to log into my school website that utilizes aspx with requests in order to scrape some data. My problem is similar to the one described here:
 [Log in to ASP website using Python's Requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193278/log-in-to-asp-website-using-pythons-requests-module) 
However, my form also requires SubmitButton.x and SubmitButton.y and I don't know where to get them form. I tried to pass in values that worked in manual login, but it didn't work.

[Here's the page](https://adfslight.resman.pl/LoginPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f%3fwa%3dwsignin1.0%26wtrealm%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fcufs.resman.pl%253a443%252frzeszow%252fAccount%252fLogOn%26wctx%3drm%253d0%2526id%253dADFS%2526ru%253d%25252frzeszow%25252fFS%25252fLS%25253fwa%25253dwsignin1.0%252526wtrealm%25253dhttps%2525253a%2525252f%2525252fuonetplus.resman.pl%2525252frzeszow%2525252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%252526wctx%25253dhttps%2525253a%2525252f%2525252fuonetplus.resman.pl%2525252frzeszow%2525252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%26wct%3d2018-02-04T18%253a54%253a58Z&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fcufs.resman.pl%3a443%2frzeszow%2fAccount%2fLogOn&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dADFS%26ru%3d%252frzeszow%252fFS%252fLS%253fwa%253dwsignin1.0%2526wtrealm%253dhttps%25253a%25252f%25252fuonetplus.resman.pl%25252frzeszow%25252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%2526wctx%253dhttps%25253a%25252f%25252fuonetplus.resman.pl%25252frzeszow%25252fLoginEndpoint.aspx&wct=2018-02-04T18%3a54%3a58Z)

[form data from successful manual login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPSZo.png)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data = {}

with requests.Session() as s:
    page = s.get('https://adfslight.resman.pl/LoginPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f%3fwa%3dwsignin1.0%26wtrealm%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fcufs.resman.pl%253a443%252frzeszow%252fAccount%252fLogOn%26wctx%3drm%253d0%2526id%253dADFS%2526ru%253d%25252frzeszow%25252fFS%25252fLS%25253fwa%25253dwsignin1.0%252526wtrealm%25253dhttps%2525253a%2525252f%2525252fuonetplus.resman.pl%2525252frzeszow%2525252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%252526wctx%25253dhttps%2525253a%2525252f%2525252fuonetplus.resman.pl%2525252frzeszow%2525252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%26wct%3d2018-02-04T18%253a08%253a18Z&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fcufs.resman.pl%3a443%2frzeszow%2fAccount%2fLogOn&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dADFS%26ru%3d%252frzeszow%252fFS%252fLS%253fwa%253dwsignin1.0%2526wtrealm%253dhttps%25253a%25252f%25252fuonetplus.resman.pl%25252frzeszow%25252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%2526wctx%253dhttps%25253a%25252f%25252fuonetplus.resman.pl%25252frzeszow%25252fLoginEndpoint.aspx&wct=2018-02-04T18%3a08%3a18Z').content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    data["__EVENTTARGET"] = ""
    data["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = ""
    data["___VIEWSTATE"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")["value"]
    data["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"]
    data["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]
    data["UsernameTextBox"] = "myusername"
    data["PasswordTextBox"] = "mypassword"
    data["SubmitButton.x"] = "49"
    data["SubmitButton.y"] = "1"

    s.post('https://adfslight.resman.pl/LoginPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f%3fwa%3dwsignin1.0%26wtrealm%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fcufs.resman.pl%253a443%252frzeszow%252fAccount%252fLogOn%26wctx%3drm%253d0%2526id%253dADFS%2526ru%253d%25252frzeszow%25252fFS%25252fLS%25253fwa%25253dwsignin1.0%252526wtrealm%25253dhttps%2525253a%2525252f%2525252fuonetplus.resman.pl%2525252frzeszow%2525252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%252526wctx%25253dhttps%2525253a%2525252f%2525252fuonetplus.resman.pl%2525252frzeszow%2525252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%26wct%3d2018-02-04T18%253a08%253a18Z&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fcufs.resman.pl%3a443%2frzeszow%2fAccount%2fLogOn&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dADFS%26ru%3d%252frzeszow%252fFS%252fLS%253fwa%253dwsignin1.0%2526wtrealm%253dhttps%25253a%25252f%25252fuonetplus.resman.pl%25252frzeszow%25252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%2526wctx%253dhttps%25253a%25252f%25252fuonetplus.resman.pl%25252frzeszow%25252fLoginEndpoint.aspx&wct=2018-02-04T18%3a08%3a18Z', data=data)
    open_page = s.get("https://uonetplus.resman.pl/rzeszow/Start.mvc/Index")

    print(open_page.text)
```

Comment: The x, y values are not important, juts set them to 0 and try with user-agent and referer in headers.